# Is there a way to preserve VM options between Install4j releases?

Tags: installation, install4j

We are currently trying to find a way to reuse user's VM options between major version releases. Currently the application keeps creating new `.vmoptions` files for each new major release. This has resulted in us having multiple `.vmoptions` files in the installation directory. It would be ideal if we could detect `.vmoptions` files from previous releases and include them with the new build. I have not been able to find an easy way to do this. Am I missing something easy?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the content of the generated .vmoptions file to something like

```
-include-options ~/Library/Preferences/MyApp.vmoptions
```

and ask the user to edit `~/Library/Preferences/MyApp.vmoptions` which will remain fixed for multiple releases. The location of the includes file is platform-specific, you can set it to `${installer:vmOptionsLocation}` and use a "Replace installer variables in text files" action to replace it with a value that you set to that installer variable in the installer, for example with a "Set a variable" action.